# ajax call getting cancelled for Spring MVC webapp

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send a JSON string to method "foo_insert_udpate" in my Spring MVC controller "BaseController" using a jQuery ajax call. The server is localhost started from within my Eclipse session.

index.jsp--------

```
function popupFoo_update_submit() {
   aRowData = $('#form_popupFoo_update').serializeArray();
   var sRowData = JSON.stringify( aRowData);
   console.log( "sRowData is ", sRowData);
   $.ajax({
     url: 'foo_insert_update',
     type: "post",
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: sRowData,
     success: function( response) {
         console.log( response);
         $('#fooTable').row( this).data( response).draw( false);    
     },
     error: function( e) {
         console.log(e);
         alert( "Error on update: " + e.message)
     }            
   });
}
```

BaseController-----

```
@RequestMapping(value="foo_insert_update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String fooUpdateHandler( @RequestParam String json_InnString)
{
    logger.info("entering fooUpdateHandler with " + json_InnString);

    String json_OutString = null;
    // do stuff to populate json_OutString

    logger.info("exiting  fooUpdateHandler with " + json_OutString);
    return json_OutString;
}
```

The js function executes and sRowData does get populated and the ajax call does fire, with the result being the error-block of the ajax executes and e.messsage is undefined, and looking in the log file reveals that fooUpdateHandler never gets entered and the "console" tab of my chrome debugger shows the post is returning a 400 error.

Any ideas on how to a) fix and/or b) further debug this?

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: have you tried changing the ajax target url to `http://localhost:<PORT>/<CONTEXT_ROOT>/foo_insert_update` ?

Comment: Yes, still throwing the 400 error

Answer (score 0):

try this shortened implementation of your method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo_insert_update", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String fooUpdateHandler(@RequestBody String json) {
    return json;
}
```

...the `@RequestParam` annotation can only be used to map URL parameters to the annotated method parameter, e.g. http://www.google.de?q=searchphrase (q is a request param with value 'searchparam') - you want to map a JSON object that will be sent in the body of your HTTP request... therefore, you have to use Spring's `@RequestBody` annotation!

Comment: some small progress: now throws a 404. Seems like I'm not getting either the value in @RequestMapping and/or the url in the ajax call matched up right

Comment: do controller methods handling GET requests work if you call their url in browser or via curl?

Comment: Instead of fooling around with these relative paths, is @Url.Action available for use in a Spring MVC webapp or is that an ASP.NET-only thingy ?

Comment: More progress - I saw where the ajax call was NOT prepending the document root to the relative path - entering the complete url did indeed bring up my controller method. So it's definitely some subtle path configuration thing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the contextPath to the url of the ajax call

```
url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foo_insert_update',
```

Thanks to all who replied!

CASE CLOSED

code_warrior